# `sbt` listing the loaded external libraries

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there any `sbt` task that I can list all of the external dependencies which are loaded? 
Sth like what intellij is doing here: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show externalDependencyClasspath
```